# PHP how to save values cookies/sessions

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am making a simple game using PHP.

I need to store certain things like what round of the game is going on and what the total is etc and save this data and have access to it later(on another page or when I come back to this page)

I tried using sessions but this isn't working out for me.

Can I do this using cookies?

This is my first time using PHP.

Here is my code if it helps to understand:

```
<form method="get" action= "skunk.php">
    <h1>PLAY SKUNK</h1>

    ROLL AGAIN? <br> 
    yes<input type="radio" name="role2" value="yes"/>
    no<input type="radio" name="role2" value="no"/>
    <br>
    <input type="submit"/>

    </form>

<?php 

session_start();
    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
    $_SESSION["n"] = array(0);
    $_SESSION["k2"] = array(0);
    $rand = 0;
    $rand2 = 0;
    $_SESSION["round"] = 1;
    if($_REQUEST["role2"] == "yes"){
        $rand = rand (1, 6);
        $rand2 = rand(1, 6);
         if($rand == 1 and $rand ==1){
            switch ($_SESSION["round"]) {
                case 1:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["n"] = array(0);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $_SESSION["s"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k1"] =array(0);
                    $_SESSION["u"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["n"] = array(0);
                    $_SESSION["k2"] = array(0); 
                    break;
            }
         }
         if($rand > 1 and $rand2 > 1) {
            switch ($_SESSION["round"]) {
                case 1:
                    array_push($_SESSION["s"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    array_push($_SESSION["k1"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    array_push($_SESSION["u"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    array_push($_SESSION["n"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    array_push($_SESSION["k2"], $rand, $rand2);
                    break;
            }
            $_SESSION["round"]++;
        }

        if($_SESSION["round"] > 5){
            session_destroy();
        }
        echo "you rolled: " . $rand . "\n";
        echo "you rolled: " . $rand2;

    }

?>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1" >
          <tr>
            <td>S</td>
            <td>K</td> 
            <td>U</td>
            <td>N</td>
            <td>K</td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width:100%" border="1" >
          <tr>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["s"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["k1"]); ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["u"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["n"]); ?></td>
            <td><?php echo array_sum($_SESSION["k2"]); ?></td>
          </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: this question is a bit different. I am asking how I should do this.

Comment: I think maybe sessions is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use session only for user log status check, and store all other data into db it would make it easier to manage and more consistent.